# Laravel Cashier fake user subscription for tests

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I'm using Laravel's Cashier for billing which is great. I'm trying to be good and keep my code tested but I'm having trouble "faking" a user with a subscription.

I've tried:

```
$user = App\Models\User::create([
  'first_name'    => $this->faker->firstName,
  'last_name'     => $this->faker->lastName,
  'email'         => $this->faker->email,
  'password'      => 'password1234',
  'stripe_plan'   => 'name_of_plan',
  'stripe_active' => 1
]);

$this->be($user);
```

But if I then check `$user->onPlan('name_of_plan')` I get `false` :(

Is there a way to do this? As I'm sure you can appreciate I don't really want to launch the payment system until I've got tests to back it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that 'stripe_plan' and 'stripe_active' are defined as fillable for User.  If they aren't then it may not be actually setting those values in User::create() which is why your test fails.

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract, BillableContract {
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword, Billable;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 
        'last_name', 
        'email', 
        'password', 
        'stripe_plan', 
        'stripe_active'
    ];

}
```